# Is there any boilerplate available for node.js/express.js project ? What practises should be followed in node projects?

Tags: node.js, express, project-structure

I want to list out the ways that is necessary to write modular code structure that is used for scalable apps.

Is there any boilerplate, project structure or best practises available for writing scalable code?

Comment: What's your definition of 'scalable'? Yes, there may be boilerplates and best practices. The question is off-topic on SO.

Comment: There are lots of boilerplates around, which may or may not be suited to what you are trying to achieve. The question is way too broad for StackOverflow IMHO.

Comment: Scalable in terms of code that is properly structured and if there are more functionalities and apps added to node project, despite of that,  it should look like well structure @estus

Comment: Can you please suggest me some of them? I am newbie to Node.js @Pierre

Comment: I'd suggest to search on GH for "express boilerplate" and "express starter".